# Does the Android advertising id change when the android device is reset (Factory Reset)?

Tags: android

i want to know does the android advertising id change when the android device is reset.

In my project am handling condition with aid, when the device is rebooted it doesnt working.

Comment: put your code so people know your mistake . Nobody is magician here...

Answer (score 5):

The answer is NO. AdvertisingId value is related to your Google acount, not specific phone.

Check: http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2316491/reset-google-advertising-android.html

Cheers!